# What are your favorite hardware deals sites?

Tags: hardware

I hope this is not off topic, after all many of us are in charge of buying and/or replacing the machines and equipment that we maintain, so I'm curious ...

What sites do you go to find the good deals on hardware, components, and gadgets and why? What's its competitive advantage?

I'll post mine below.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I picked up a few more to add to my list. I'm also glad that there were some international suggestions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here my answer/list to start ... I find that aggregator deal sites that are either completely or mostly tech focused are best. If a good deal pops up Amazon.com, Geeks.com, etc., they'll quickly appear on the aggregators, too, but there are some exceptions where to wait is to possibly miss out (woot!).

I regularly search these for myself & my clients (or just a bit of procrastination). I save them in a *firefox folder and use "Open All in Tabs" almost daily*.

[dealcritic.com](http://dealcritic.com) - people vote up the best deals, so you immediately get a sense of how much of a value it is

[bensbargains.net](http://bensbargains.net) - has trackers for certain hot products, quick, simple search

[fatwallet.com](http://fatwallet.com) - good for finding coupon codes and discussion on various deals if you're unsure of the product or merchant

[dealnews.com](http://dealnews.com) - wide range of deals and coupon codes

[dealnews.com/memory](http://dealnews.com/memory) (aka dealram) - quickly find the best prices on the exact ram you need

[pricewatch.com](http://pricewatch.com) - great categorization, numerous merchants, great for searching when you need a certain type of product but you don't need a particular brand or model

[froogle.com](http://froogle.com) - quickly find an exact product (brand & model), but i prefer pricewatch for product types

Comment: +1 for pricewatch - been using it for years...

Answer (score 2):

NewEgg.com - Excellent comments and voting on the products and the best prices

TigerDirect.com, CompUSA.com, & InfoTelDistributors.com - Good prices and selection, easy to purchase items from them.

These are the sites that I have found a great many good deals for hardware.

-JFV

Answer (score 2):

Another aggregator site that I sometimes find good deal through:
[www.techbargains.com](http://www.techbargains.com/)

Answer (score 2):

For the UK I like [dabs.com](http://dabs.com) and [ebuyer.com](http://ebuyer.com)

Answer (score 1):

You can stay apprised of various *deals of the day* with desktop application [Wootalyzer](http://www.wootalyzer.com/). It has a General/Tech section with [Newegg](http://www.newegg.com), [Pacific Geek](http://www.pacificgeek.com), [Buy.com](http://www.buy.com), [Tiger Direct](http://www.tigerdirect.com), and others.

(Also many other non-tech DotD sites.)

Of course something useful needs to be offered, and don't buy impulsively. You can get some of the best deals this way but remember to compare prices; frequently something you want but don't yet need isn't truly discounted enough compared to the competition to warrant immediate purchase. By the time you do it may have dropped to an equivalent price anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I find [dealspl.us](http://www.dealspl.us) has some sweet deals from across a whole assortment of categories.  That + categories and RSS feeds plus a nice search makes me a deal addict.

Comment: Nice interface! I like the voting. Good one.

Answer (score 1):

German speaking area, http://www.switchshop24.de/ has some amazing deals, also used.

Edit: Also http://geizhals.at/ (ger as well) is a great top prices aggregator, but I guess every sysadmin in the German-speaking world know that already. :)

Answer (score 1):

For deals or specials, I agree with some of the sites already mentioned, Tiger Direct, New Egg, etc.  For everyday low prices I prefer to use [www.provantage.com](http://www.provantage.com).  Rarely do I find deals on their website, but I find their prices hard to beat on day to day buying of items.

Of course, everything comes with a price, and their customer service and pre-sales support leaves a lot to be desired.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.redflagdeals.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=9&daysprune=30&prefixid=Comp9

People looking for deal and posting only the most interesting...  and got comment about the deal.  Also there's others sections for other stuff.

However, mostly consumer component.

Answer (score 1):

[CouponRefund.com](http://www.couponrefund.com) is my favorite hardware deal site. There are so many deals and coupon site but I like this just because of their user friendly interface and latest coupons.

Answer (score 0):

We had good luck with CDW over the years.  The prices are decent, support is good, and they integrate with lots of purchasing groups, which saves us a few bucks here and there.